# Best way to set up git for magento

Tags: magento-1.9, installation, git

I have dedicated server with multiple magento installations e.g 
1.Production 
2.Dev 
3.Blogs 
all magento installations are set up under separate secondary domains. However production has a dedicated IP and all other installations are on separate IP address.

What is the best way to set up git? should I install it in root to controll all files in one repo or it's better to set up separate repos in each installation?

Thanks.

Comment: and is this for one magento site going trough dev, stage to production? if so then one repo and separate branches

Comment: Yes dev is an exact copy of production.

Comment: only it never is but yeah in this case have them in separate repos and bring in changes between branches with rebase after merging the pullrequests

Comment: Nr 3, Blogs... What kind of installation is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to have one GIT repo that controls all your code and use Branches to separate out what code is checked out where. So for example you should use the MASTER branch for product and you could create a staging branch for staging and a development branch for dev.